# When implementing a VSPackage (VSIX) for VS2015, how do I get my new commands listed in Options-Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, visual-studio-2015, vsix, vspackage

I have just created my first VSPackage (since VS2015 doesn't support AddIns).

While I have managed to assign keyboard shortcuts within my VSPackage (using KeyBindings), I have found that the commands themselves do not seem to be listed within the Options-Keyboard tab in Visual Studio.

I notice that the other extensions that I have installed include their commands for assigning within Options-Keyboard.

What must I do to get mine included?

Here are the full contents of my VSCT file - apologies if there's a better way to attach this, but I couldn't find one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!--  This is the file that defines the actual layout and type of the commands.
        It is divided in different sections (e.g. command definition, command
        placement, ...), with each defining a specific set of properties.
        See the comment before each section for more details about how to
        use it. -->

  <!--  The VSCT compiler (the tool that translates this file into the binary
        format that VisualStudio will consume) has the ability to run a preprocessor
        on the vsct file; this preprocessor is (usually) the C++ preprocessor, so
        it is possible to define includes and macros with the same syntax used
        in C++ files. Using this ability of the compiler here, we include some files
        defining some of the constants that we will use inside the file. -->

  <!--This is the file that defines the IDs for all the commands exposed by VisualStudio. -->
  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h" />

  <!--This header contains the command ids for the menus provided by the shell. -->
  <Extern href="vsshlids.h" />

  <!--The Commands section is where commands, menus, and menu groups are defined.
      This section uses a Guid to identify the package that provides the command defined inside it. -->
  <Commands package="guidDanBarPackage">
    <!-- Inside this section we have different sub-sections: one for the menus, another
    for the menu groups, one for the buttons (the actual commands), one for the combos
    and the last one for the bitmaps used. Each element is identified by a command id that
    is a unique pair of guid and numeric identifier; the guid part of the identifier is usually
    called "command set" and is used to group different command inside a logically related
    group; your package should define its own command set in order to avoid collisions
    with command ids defined by other packages. -->

    <Menus>
        <Menu guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbar" type="Toolbar">
            <CommandFlag>DefaultDocked</CommandFlag>
            <Strings>
                <ButtonText>Dan Bar</ButtonText>
                <CommandName>Dan Bar</CommandName>
            </Strings>
        </Menu>
    </Menus>

    <Menus>
        <Menu guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="BriefToolbar" type="Toolbar">
            <CommandFlag>DefaultDocked</CommandFlag>
            <Strings>
                <ButtonText>Dan Brief Bar</ButtonText>
                <CommandName>Dan Brief Bar</CommandName>
            </Strings>
        </Menu>
    </Menus>

    <!-- In this section you can define new menu groups. A menu group is a container for
         other menus or buttons (commands); from a visual point of view you can see the
         group as the part of a menu contained between two lines. The parent of a group
         must be a menu. -->
    <Groups>
      <Group guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" priority="0x0000">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbar" />
      </Group>

      <Group guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="BriefToolbarGroup" priority="0x0000">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="BriefToolbar" />
      </Group>
    </Groups>

    <!--Buttons section. -->
    <!--This section defines the elements the user can interact with, like a menu command or a button
        or combo box in a toolbar. -->
    <Buttons>
      <!--To define a menu group you have to specify its ID, the parent menu and its display priority.
          The command is visible and enabled by default. If you need to change the visibility, status, etc, you can use
          the CommandFlag node.
          You can add more than one CommandFlag node e.g.:
              <CommandFlag>DefaultInvisible</CommandFlag>
              <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
          If you do not want an image next to your command, remove the Icon node /> -->
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidConcurrentBuilds" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Set Concurrent Builds</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidTrackInSolutionExplorer" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic2" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Track In Solution Explorer</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBuildStartupProject" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic3" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Build Startup Project</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidCommentOutParam" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic4" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Comment Out Parameter</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidInsertRegion" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic5" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Insert Region</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidXMLCommentFull" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic6" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Full XML Comment</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidXMLCommentSmall" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic7" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Small XML Comment</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidXMLCommentTiny" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic8" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Tiny XML Comment</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidXMLCommentMember" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic9" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Member XML Comment</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidVSStd97" id="cmdidMoreWindows" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="MyToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidDanBarImages" id="bmpPic10" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Win...</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>

      <!--BRIEF buttons-->
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefAltD" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="BriefToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidBriefBarImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Brief Alt D - Line Delete</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefAltMinus" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="BriefToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidBriefBarImages" id="bmpPic3" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Brief Num-Minus - Line Cut</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefAltPlus" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
      <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="BriefToolbarGroup" />
      <Icon guid="guidBriefBarImages" id="bmpPic4" />
      <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Brief Num-Plus - Line Copy</ButtonText>
      </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefAltC" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="BriefToolbarGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidBriefBarImages" id="bmpPic2" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Brief Alt C - Block Select</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefLinePaste" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
      <Parent guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="BriefToolbarGroup" />
      <Icon guid="guidBriefBarImages" id="bmpPic5" />
      <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Brief Insert - Line Paste</ButtonText>
      </Strings>
      </Button>

    </Buttons>

    <!--The bitmaps section is used to define the bitmaps that are used for the commands.-->
    <Bitmaps>
      <!--  The bitmap id is defined in a way that is a little bit different from the others:
            the declaration starts with a guid for the bitmap strip, then there is the resource id of the
            bitmap strip containing the bitmaps and then there are the numeric ids of the elements used
            inside a button definition. An important aspect of this declaration is that the element id
            must be the actual index (1-based) of the bitmap inside the bitmap strip. -->
      <Bitmap guid="guidDanBarImages" href="Resources\DanBar.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPic3, bmpPic4, bmpPic5, bmpPic6, bmpPic7, bmpPic8, bmpPic9, bmpPic10" />
      <Bitmap guid="guidBriefBarImages" href="Resources\BriefBar.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPic3, bmpPic4, bmpPic5, bmpPic6" />
    </Bitmaps>
  </Commands>

  <KeyBindings>
      <KeyBinding guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidXMLCommentSmall" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="q" mod1="Alt" />
      <KeyBinding guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefAltD" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="d" mod1="Alt" />
      <KeyBinding guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefAltMinus" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="VK_SUBTRACT" />
      <KeyBinding guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefAltPlus" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="VK_ADD" />
      <KeyBinding guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefAltC" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="c" mod1="Alt" />
      <KeyBinding guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefLinePaste" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="VK_INSERT" />
  </KeyBindings>

  <Symbols>
    <!-- This is the package guid. -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidDanBarPackage" value="{69fa005b-6bae-4a69-84e6-ed7cf75cc180}" />

    <!-- This is the guid used to group the menu commands together -->
    <GuidSymbol name="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" value="{a2ce5715-189e-4bfc-bc37-4d1b6e0c1122}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyToolbar" value="0x1000" />
      <IDSymbol name="MyToolbarGroup" value="0x1050" />
      <IDSymbol name="BriefToolbar" value="0x1100" />
      <IDSymbol name="BriefToolbarGroup" value="0x1150" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidConcurrentBuilds" value="256" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidTrackInSolutionExplorer" value="257" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidBuildStartupProject" value="258" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidCommentOutParam" value="259" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidXMLCommentFull" value="260" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidXMLCommentSmall" value="261" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidXMLCommentTiny" value="262" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidXMLCommentMember" value="263" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidInsertRegion" value="264" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidBriefAltD" value="270" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidBriefAltMinus" value="271" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidBriefAltPlus" value="272" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidBriefAltC" value="273" />
      <IDSymbol name="cmdidBriefLinePaste" value="274" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol name="guidDanBarImages" value="{ffb25733-9517-4411-bae2-4deda791fd6c}">
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic3" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic4" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic5" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic6" value="6" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic7" value="7" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic8" value="8" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic9" value="9" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic10" value="10" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol name="guidBriefBarImages" value="{f1a36fcd-2c27-4151-ae23-42fff88c212c}">
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic3" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic4" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic5" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic6" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>

  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, a command belongs to a menu and is included in Options-Keyboard from this menu. As your commands belong only to a toolbar, this is not the case.

You can add the **LocCanonicalName** tag to your .vsct button definitions to include your commands to Options-Keyboard like this:

```
 <Strings>
   <LocCanonicalName>DanBar.TrackInSolutionExplorer</LocCanonicalName>
   <ButtonText>Track In Solution Explorer</ButtonText>
 </Strings>
```

Comment: That's interesting.  Thanks very much @Sergey - I will give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your commands in Visual Studio Command Table (.vsct) file and create event handlers for them in code. See [Commands, Menus, and Toolbars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164627.aspx).

VS 2015 includes the **Custom Command** template that you can add to your project to quickly get started:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sergey.  Yeah, that's what I did (except for using VB.Net, as my Add-In began life as a set of macros).  I've added 2 toolbars containing a total of 10 custom-commands (and they all work), but none of these "custom commands" are listed in Options-Keyboard.  That's what has me confused.

Comment: Can you post your project or at least the .vsct file?

Comment: Thank you @Sergey.  I've included my full VSCT in the question now.

Comment: You may notice my failed attempt at renaming the standard "Windows..." button to "Win..." and associating an icon with it for inclusion in my toolbar.  This didn't work.