# Visual Studio 2017 extension not binding 'Insert' key to a command

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I've written a small extension containing my own legacy macros that I use for customising the Visual Studio editor.

In Visual Studio 2015, the following instruction bound the 'Insert' key to my command "cmdidBriefLinePaste".  Unfortunately the same line does not work in Visual Studio 2017:

```
<KeyBindings>
  <KeyBinding guid="guidDanBarPackageCmdSet" id="cmdidBriefLinePaste" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="VK_INSERT" />
</KeyBindings>
```

If I add mod1="Alt" to this then it works (but only with 'Alt' pressed, which isn't what I want).

Manually unassigning the Insert key from "Edit.OvertypeMode" makes no difference.

Could anyone please tell me either:

a) Is there a way to make this work?

b) Alternatively, how do I add my command to Visual Studio's "All Commands" so that I can perform the mapping manually through Visual Studio's Options dialog?

Comment: Do you mean it works on vs2015 with single shortcuts 'Insert', but I create a simple demo with vs2015, it does not work. I suggest that you could use combination shortcuts. In addition, as far as I know, it seems that you could not add your custom command to visual studio's 'All commands'

Comment: Thank you for giving this a try @Cole Wu.
I'm surprised that it didn't work for you in VS2015.  I managed to bind to the single 'Insert' key in VS2015 with no issues.
My problem is that I still like some of the key actions from the old Brief editor, and 'Insert' did a "line mode paste".  Seems I might have to get used to Alt-Insert.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a question that I'd posted several years ago:
[When implementing a VSPackage (VSIX) for VS2015, how do I get my new commands listed in Options-Keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099240/when-implementing-a-vspackage-vsix-for-vs2015-how-do-i-get-my-new-commands-li)

The answer was to use

```
<LocCanonicalName>Dan.BriefLinePaste</LocCanonicalName>
```

and well fancy that, it just works.  There's an example here: https://www.mztools.com/articles/2014/MZ2014019.aspx